# SQL Server - Scripting data for only rows in query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I love the "new" feature to script data as well as schema from SQL Server 2008 and forward.

However, I would like to script only a few 100 rows of a gigantic table (ie rows that match a query).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible if you use SSMSToolsPack that is a free plugin to SSMS. I use this and also asked several of my developers to use also. It has other excellent features as well as like storing the history of queries you run, color coding your servers and among others. You should at-least give it a try.

http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

Comment: Very nice tool, I did not know about.